# Update Linux Mint in Virtualbox VM behind transparent proxy

Tags: linux-mint, apt, proxy

i just install linux mint in a Vbox VM and when i try to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=True
```

i have the following output:

```
desa@desa-VirtualBox ~ $ sudo apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=True 
0% [Trabajando]GET /ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: mirror.uchile.cl
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.2.20)


Answer for: http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 22783
Connection: Close

Des:1 http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu xenial InRelease [22,8 kB]
Err:1 http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                           
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
0% [Conectando a packages.linuxmint.com (68.235.39.11)] [Conectando a security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161)] [Conectando a archive.canonical.com (GET /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: mirror.uchile.cl
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.2.20)


Answer for: http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 22791
Connection: Close

Des:2 http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [22,8 kB]                                                                         
Err:2 http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                                   
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
0% [Conectando a packages.linuxmint.com (68.235.39.11)] [Conectando a security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161)] [Conectando a archive.canonical.com (GET /ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: mirror.uchile.cl
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.2.20)


Answer for: http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 22793
Connection: Close

Des:3 http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [22,8 kB]                                                                       
Err:3 http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                                 
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
0% [Conectando a packages.linuxmint.com (68.235.39.11)] [Conectando a security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161)] [Conectando a archive.canonical.com (GET /ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: archive.canonical.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.2.20)


Answer for: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 22787
Connection: Close

Des:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [22,8 kB]                                                                            
Err:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                      
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
0% [Conectando a packages.linuxmint.com (68.235.39.11)] [Conectando a security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161)]GET /dists/sonya/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: packages.linuxmint.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.2.20)


GET /ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: security.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.2.20)


Answer for: http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/sonya/InRelease
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 22780
Connection: Close

Des:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya InRelease [22,8 kB]                                             
0% [5 InRelease 0 B/22,8 kB 0%] [Esperando las cabeceras]Answer for: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 22795
Connection: Close

Des:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [22,8 kB]
Err:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya InRelease                    
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease      
  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
Descargados 137 kB en 0s (199 kB/s) 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: Fallo al obtener http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/sonya/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: Fallo al obtener http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: Fallo al obtener http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: Fallo al obtener http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: Fallo al obtener http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: Fallo al obtener http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  El fichero firmado en claro no es válido, «NOSPLIT» obtenido (¿la red requiere autenticación?)
E: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.
```

So, the question is: How i can configurate (or passing some parameter) update my linux vm?, Thanks

Note: I follow all indications in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/24061/ but none works :(

Comment: Is the host handling NAT for the VM or does it have a direct connection out to the network (bridge or tunnel)?

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to get apt-get to work through a proxy is to add the proxy address to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://address:port";`

I am not familiar with the `-o Debug::` option. You might be able to add the same info here.